# Difference between instances and reserved instances on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In AWS EC2 console I have 2 tabs, *Instances* and *Reserved instances*.
In *Instances* I can launch instance and in Reserved instances i can only purchase.

What are difference between them?
How to launch a reserved instance?

Comment: A quick google search for `"aws reserved instances"` should answer this, as well as the billing implications. This is off-topic though: It's a purchasing/billing issue, not programming-related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved instances are only a billing feature: When you purchase reserved instances, they will be automatically assigned to your current running instances at the time of billing. The *Instances* tab is where you manage your current infrastructure.

Note that if you have reserved instances that don't match any running instance type/region/zone they won't be assigned but you'll still pay for them.

Comment: *are only a billing feature* - which I stated already in comments, and which is why the question is off topic. And trivial to find via google.